# How to parallel run the yield function (generator) in python?

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I have a function that will 'yield' a generator. Such as the following example

```
def funtion(G):
   for i in G:
      yield i*2
```

Then I have another function that tries to call this function

```
def main_function(G):
    generator = function(G)
    tt = 0
    for i in generator:
       tt = tt+i
    return tt
```

But I would like to speed up this process by using multiprocessing. Is there a good solution? I tried to change the 'function' to let it return a full list instead of a generator, but the RAM consumption is too high. Any good solutions?

Comment: `multiprocessing` will not speed this up. It has massive inter-process communication overhead, far more than the cost of just running the generator in the same process.

Comment: Also, if `G` is a numpy array, `np.sum(G*2)` will do what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks, but the i*2 is just illustration purpose. The real computation is much more complex. That’s why I hope to speed this process up.